# C++: Performance of Switch Statement vs Lookup tables

Tags: c++, c, performance, switch-statement, lookup-tables

I tried to compare the performance of `switch` statement and lookup tables as below.

This is the code using `switch` statement

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n = 3;

    for (long i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) {  
        switch (n) {
        case 0:
            printf("Alpha");
            break;
        case 1:
            printf("Beta");
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Gamma");
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Delta");
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And here is the code using lookup tables:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static char const * const Greek[4] = {
  "Alpha",
  "Beta",
  "Gamma",
  "Delta"
};

int main()
{
    int n = 3;

    for (long i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) {  
        if (n >= 0 && n < 4) {
            printf(Greek[n]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I run two program on ubuntu 14.04, gcc version 4.8.4, using perf version 4.4.13 to analyze performance. And result:

- Switch Statement: 6.764077822 seconds
- Lookup tables: 6.665140483 seconds

I don't know why Switch Statement run slower than Lookup tables. As I known, Switch Statement using jump table, i think it should run faster than Lookup tables in my program (it has additional if statement).

Comment: Your timings include the call to `printf`, which could lead to inaccurate results.

Comment: You should have a look at the generated assembly code.

Comment: and if you have optimization turned on, both `switch` and `if` will be optimized away with a good optimizing compiler.

Comment: Note that if you compile both of the with `-O3` they are identical, the compiler identifies `n=3` and removes everything related to the other cases (including the `if` and `switch`).

Comment: I recommend not trying to out-optimise modern compilers in general. In a very specific usecase (which better does not contain `printf()` or working on a single case) measure and take the faster one, without trying to reason why. That however will not be portable or survive even the tiniest change of circumstances.

Comment: I just made an edit to the code to add it back. Otherwise it will not even compile.

Comment: @Yunnosch the deleted code was redundant and the C tag is correct, because this is a valid C and C++ program.

Comment: Use the [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/) compiler explorer which shows you instantly the generated assembly code. You can chose different compilers and you can specify all compilation flags. Also change `n = 3` to `n = rand()` so the optimizer won't optimize most of the code away.

Comment: @Jonas no, if n== 4 then the `default` case is used where we have just a `break`, but this is the `break` for the `switch` statement, not for the `for` loop.

Comment: The difference is less than 1.5%. Unless it's very consistent, you can't draw any conclusions from it.

Comment: Voting to close this as "cannot be reproduced" since the incorrect benchmarking is the culprit.

Comment: This is a meaningless question on oh so many levels. C++ doesn't have any performance figures of its own, it's a specification. Specific code compiled with a speciific version of gcc  has performance figures, different from tnat of other code, or of code compiled with a different version of gcc, or on a different machine. There is no single answer like "lookup is faster" or "switch is faster" which is valid beyond your specific example.

Answer (score 10):

If you are compiling with optimizations, your code has no switch and no lookup table. I's just a for loop which calls `printf()` many times with the same fixed string. Any minimally reasonable compiler will in fact detect that `n = 3` is never changed and optimize it out. Maybe you can add a `n = rand() % 4;` just inside the loop.

On the other end if you are not compiling with optimizations, taking timings is meaningless.

Coming to your question, I expect the lookup table to be faster than the switch statement, since the switch statement will totally thrash the Branch Prediction, while the if will be no problem, being always true.

Comment: I used gcc version 4.8.4 with default option. I will try with no optimization compiler.

Comment: @tuanpm No! As I said, timing unoptimized code is meaningless! It will tell you nothing at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your benchmark is entirely inadequate to measure `switch`/lookup-table performance: Virtually all time is spend within the `printf()` calls. If there is any effect from the `switch`/lookup-table difference, it is dwarfed by the measurement-noise due to the large total runtime.

---

For reference: I expect a table lookup in a hot, tight loop to be only about ten clock-cycles. On a 2 GHz CPU, that's just 0.05 seconds for all 10000000 iterations (rough estimate, can easily be wrong by a factor of two, but that doesn't affect the overall assessment). That's on the order on 1% of your total runtime!